# input value does not work with virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I hope you can help me. I'm still a javascript beginner and I'm trying to learn this topic. I have the following problem.

I would like to use a virtual keyboard which I use for an input at a search field. The problem is now when I make the input in the search field, the names are filtered by the value. But when I make the input directly with the virtual keyboard, the Value is not filtered. What could be the problem?

**Javascript Virtual Keyboard Code**

```
const Keyboard = {
    elements: {
        main: null,
        keysContainer: null,
        keys: []
    },

    eventHandlers: {
        oninput: null,
        onclose: null
    },

    properties: {
        value: "",
        capsLock: false
    },

    init() {
        // Create main elements
        this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
        this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

        // Setup main elements
        this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
        this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
        this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys());

        this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");

        // Add to DOM
        this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
        document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

        // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
        document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
                this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
                    element.value = currentValue;
                });
            });
        });
    },

    _createKeys() {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        const keyLayout = [
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
            "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
            "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
            "space"
        ];

        // Creates HTML for an icon
        const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
            return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
        };

        keyLayout.forEach(key => {
            const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
            const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;

            // Add attributes/classes
            keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
            keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

            switch (key) {
                case "backspace":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "caps":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this._toggleCapsLock();
                        keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
                    });

                    break;

                case "enter":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += "\n";
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "space":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += " ";
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;

                case "done":
                    keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--dark");
                    keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("check_circle");

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.close();
                        this._triggerEvent("onclose");
                    });

                    break;

                default:
                    keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                    });

                    break;
            }

            fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

            if (insertLineBreak) {
                fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        });

        return fragment;
    },

    _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
        if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
            this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
        }
    },

    _toggleCapsLock() {
        this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

        for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
            if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
                key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    },

    open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
        this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
        this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
        this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
        this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
    },

    close() {
        this.properties.value = "";
        this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
        this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
        this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
    }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    Keyboard.init();
});
```

**Javascript Search Function**

```
function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('search');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the link to my code pen: https://codepen.io/siad/pen/jOYLJVW

I hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can see on codepen that you use the `onkeyup` property, that triggers the `search()` function when you release a key on your physical keyboard.

Because your virtual keyboard is not a real keyboard, it does not have a keyup event handler, so it does not trigger the function.

One thing you can try is to call the `search()` function in your key click event as follow:

```js
// Starting from line 123
                default:
                    keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
                        this._triggerEvent("oninput");
                        search(); // <- Here is my edit
                    });

                    break;
```

Maybe there's a better way, but this should work, I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hello Théo

Thank you for your suggested solution.

This is a possible variant. However, deleting the text in the input bar does not reset the search. Of course, you could also call the search() function again at the backspace.

Also, the webkit search cancel button (x) is not displayed on the far right. I think there should be a better solution for this yet.

Comment: You're right! In this case, if you want to refresh the results on each key of the virtual keyboard you can add the search function in the _triggerEvent function, it seems to be working well